# web form builder (generator)

Tags: forms, orbeon, xforms

I'm starting a comparison study about web forms generators technologies before coding a new one (why reinventing the wheel?). I would like to know if XForms is a standard that would be the the best choice for that ?

would you have any return of experience using libraries or tools written in java to generate web forms and surveys  with java/xml/xslt ?

For example tools which support persistance with hibernate also ?
I'm now watching Orbeon Form builder using XForms and XPL, but i suppose others tools exist in the java  world ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this question fits well with the Stack Overflow format, as it is hard to come up with an answer that would be accepted by most specialists in the field. I.e., this seems more a matter of taste and opinion. Maybe editing your question to include specific requirements would help?

Comment: In order to introduce the matter it's related to the choice of XForms or not and the best way to implement this solution with server side technologies and hibernate support (to store fields, response, labels). The genericity of the topic here is on purpose, anyway it's java/xml oriented for specifications.

Answer (score 2):

XForms could be the best choice, depending on your needs. For sure, it is an standard, but using it depends on what you want to accomplish.

If you need simple forms, that you can store as row columns, you have [Forms on Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/87809?hl=en), but if you need complex forms to build XML Documents, XForms is the choice.

Take in account that the storage must be an XML database to take advantage of the full power of XForms. Take a look at [eXist-db](http://exist-db.org/) (built on Java) or [BaseX](http://basex.org/) for example. In Java was a project called [XIndice](https://xml.apache.org/xindice/) but it has been abandoned right now.

Maybe [this project from Steve Cameron](http://www.pozible.com/project/27074) could interest you before reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've finally doing my own solution in EJB3 (using dynaform eXtension with primefaces). Orbeon was an interesting choice at first glance, the problem was being stucked with their runtime implementation. Anyway, Xforms is definitely a good path to follow (as all standards supported by W3C), but for short-terms project, my customer and I have chosen a full Java stack solution , i mean without xslt manipulation.

BR